# How to add chrome to AWS Lambda Api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm making an Api that returns a pdf by puppeteer. I just instaled puppeteer with `npm install chrome-Aws-lambda`, `install puppeteer --save-dev` but when I run the Api, I get this exception.

[image]

I tried runing npm install but it doesn't work, how can I install chromium or make puppeteer works???

this is my code and package.json

```
let browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com");

    const pdf = await page.pdf({
        format: "A4",
        printBackground: false,
        preferCSSPageSize: true,
        displayHeaderFooter: false,

        headerTemplate: `<div class="header" style="font-size:20px; padding-left:15px;"><h1>Main Heading</h1></div> `,
        footerTemplate: '<footer><h5>Page <span class="pageNumber"></span> of <span class="totalPages"></span></h5></footer>',
        margin: { top: "200px", bottom: "150px", right: "20px", left: "20px" },
        height: "200px",
        width: "200px",
    });

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        //  Uncomment below to enable CORS requests
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
        },
        body: pdf
    };
```

Pakage:

```
{
"name": "amplifysandboxpdf",
"version": "2.0.0",
"description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
"main": "index.js",
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92",
  "@types/puppeteer": "^5.4.6",
"puppeteer": "^17.1.2"
},
"dependencies": {
   "chrome-aws-lambda": "^10.1.0",
   "puppeteer-core": "^10.0.0"
  } 
}
```

Comment: How are you adding your package to lambda?

Comment: @AAron I'm just pushing it with my project, I don't use Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when you upload a zip to lambda, you need to provide both - your source code and node_modules (modules can also be added as a lambda layer). In your case error is because of missing package, so the first place I'd look at is the zip you provide to lambda and does it contain all the necessary packages

I see in your package.json you have both puppeteer and puppeteer-core. Puppeteer downloads chromium on installation (that's the bit that errors for you). First you need to decide if puppeteer is even necessary, maybe core package is enough, but if it is necessary - once again, it should be in your zip that you provide.

I'm not sure about how puppeteer does this, but if it downloads chromium into node_modules it should work once your zip file is correctly packaged. Otherwise, you might need to create your own docker container by using puppeteer base image [Puppeteer base image](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#running-in-docker).
If this is the case, these are the steps you need to take:

- Create a dockerfile with puppeteer base image, build your own image and make sure your application is installed in there. Example of what this file could look like:

```
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:16.1.0

WORKDIR /home/pptruser/app
ADD ./package-lock.json /home/pptruser/app/package-lock.json
ADD ./package.json /home/pptruser/app/package.json
RUN npm ci
# Customize the line below - copy files that your application requires
ADD ./src/. /home/pptruser/app/src/
# Remove development dependencies (in your case puppeteer is not a devDependency)
RUN npm prune --production

CMD [ "index.js" ]
```

- Test locally if it works in the container and later publish this image to ECR (AWS registry for docker containers)
- Launch lambda by using the image instead of using NodeJS environment

Comment: I installed puppeteer because it worked for me when I got this error in local, so I thought it was needed for Lambda too, and do I need docker to make this work?

Comment: ohh i almost forgot I can't install chromium in my lambda, or a layer because chromium size is 300mb and layers are capped at 200mb unzip

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you package your code in docker container instead of using default NodeJS runtime on lambda. Your use case requires custom software ready and available in the runtime, it's not really how lambdas are usually used, but that's why lambda docker exists. This way you can set up your custom dependencies and still keep using lambda. Just keep in mind that bigger lambda runtime means longer cold start.
You can find more instructions on how to set up your container here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-alt